# Htaccess Rewrite Rule with Page Not Found issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

htaccess question on rewrite rules

I have 3 files in my folder

```
create.php
index.html
index.php
```

and I got this as my .htaccess for rewrite rules

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin/

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ permissions/index.php?action=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

The issue is I want to access the site

```
http://member.mydomain.com/admin/permissions/create
```

But it tell me

```
The requested URL /admin/create.php was not found on this server.
```

Is there something wrong with my .htaccess , the rewrite rule is mainly for index.php to do its query sending, I would like my create.php to be accessible with the path of

```
 http://member.mydomain.com/admin/permissions/create
```

**Thanks** !!

Updated .htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ permissions/index.php?action=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

But it return same error

```
Not Found

The requested URL /admin/permissions/create was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your code you have only:

```
# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

However just that does not take into account weather or not the file actually exists or not before redirecting, you want something like:

```
# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/admin/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule /([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

**You would also need to place this rule at the top of your rules.**

This is the entire set of rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/admin/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule /([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Your do nothing rule is not required.

Comment: I added your permission to the top of my htaccess but it still say admin/create.php not found, i updated my question with the new .htaccess , thanks !

Comment: You saved me from a big headache! Thank you very much!